# Dynamic update in Water bubble js

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the below code first time if i (any higher value)gave value = 29 the chart increases, second time if i give value less than 29 it doesn't work, level still stays in 29 but inside data has changed but not represented in chart. i cross checked in console. in waterbubble chart increase by value, but not decreasing by value. once higher value is given it is not reducing to lower value in chart

```js
function s(){
 var waterFill = document.getElementById("db01").value;
  var fraction = waterFill / 100;
  $('#demo-1').waterbubble({
   txt: ('' + waterFill).slice(-3).toString() + " %",
    data: fraction,
    animation: true
  });
 console.log(waterFill);}
 setInterval(function(){ s();// this will run after every 10 seconds
}, 10000);
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Customizable-Liquid-Bubble-Chart-With-jQuery-Canvas/waterbubble.js"></script>

<input id="db01" onkeyup="s()">
<div class=" col-lg-4">
<canvas id="demo-1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [newer chart code](https://github.com/fiona23/water-bubble-chart) from the author's github repo..

Comment: @Annarfych i tried it remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by changing in function NewValue(),

```js
 function NewValue(){
 var data = document.getElementById("db01").value;
       if(data > .5){
            return Math.round(data*100);
        } else {
            return (data*100).toFixed(1);
        }
    }
```